# How to run a java code inside a flutter assets?

Tags: java, flutter

Is there a way to run a java code inside flutter asset? I've tried using [starflut](https://pub.dev/packages/starflut/) but it doesn't work the way I wanted it to be.

I want to use this to develop something for my future flutter projects.

So here's how I want it to be:

```
<my_flutter_app>/assets/java/myJavaCode.java
this is the path of my java code that I want to run or call
```

And I want it to be used inside my flutter app.

Comment: What, and how you have been trying this use case?  Can you please share more details around ?

Comment: There is a java code that I want to implement inside my flutter app using method calls are not acceptable since I have to implement it on every platform including web. I have only did it this day and found some bridge like starflut to run different language script but suddenly it is not working. I dont know if its because I am using flutter 2.0 or my implementation was bad